# Could not load type "app_filter": class does not exist

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I have upgraded the symfony 2.8 project to symfony 3.4. After fixing some issue I am getting the above issue when loading the page which has form with filters.

The app_filter attribute is configured in my form.yml file inside the bundle/resources/config directory and it looks like the below,

```
parameters:
     app.abstract_filter.form.type.class: AppBundle\Form\Type\Filter\FilterType

services:
app.abstract_filter.form.type:
        class: '%app.abstract_filter.form.type.class%'
        arguments:
            - '@translator.default'
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_filter}

    app.abstract_filter.form:
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        factory: ['@form.factory', createNamed]
        arguments:
            - 'app_filter'
            - '%app.abstract_filter.form.type.class%'
```

app_abstract_fitler_form_type class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type\Filter;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;

class FilterType extends AbstractType
{

    /** @var  Translator */
    protected $translator;

    /** @var  EntityManager */
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_filter';
    }
}
```

Comment: what's app_filter is it a service ?

Comment: have you tried writting it like this `'@app_filter'` I think it could be your `app.abstract_filter.form` failing you

Comment: @db306: Thanks. I have tried it but it is now throwing the following error, The service "app.abstract_filter.form" has a dependency on a non-existent service "app_filter". Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Can you post your `app.abstract_filter.form` class and the one concerning `app.abstract_filter.form.type` ?

Comment: @db306: Added the class. Please check